# In course schedule II : Leetcode, how can we ensure when there are multiple answers the solution is the one with increasing order of course number?

Tags: java, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs, topological-sort, cycle-detection

When there are multiple solutions, I want to return the solution where courses are in ascending order. How can I do that by the topological sort algorithm?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this using PriorityQueue in place of Queue.